# Debugging in VS - Autos section?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Does anyone know what a variable highlighted in red means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means its value was changed since the last time the program was stopped in the debugger. For example, if you write the code: `int a = 10; a = 20;`, and step over it with F10, you'll notice the variable 'a' turns red when you step over the second line.

Answer (score 0):

In VS check at Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors to find out what setting matches your colors.